# Is using xargs faster than not using it?

Tags: xargs

Is this faster:

```
find /tmp -name core -type f | xargs /bin/rm -f
```

than doing this:

```
find /tmp -name core -type f -exec /bin/rm -f {} \;
```

So would using `xargs` increase overall speed?

(I got the example from the man page of `xargs`.)

Comment: Even faster is `find /tmp -name core -type f -delete` - no extra processes at all.

Comment: Indeed, but it is requiring a Gnu specific extension. `-exec rm -f {} +` is the fastest still portable (POSIX) way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Mat already said, in the general case you should be aware of the fact that **every** byte can be in a filename, except the `NUL` character (as it delimits the end of the string) and the `/` (as it deleimits path elements). So your `xargs` example should be (on a GNU system)

```
find /tmp -name core -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```

Equivalent is a `-exec` in the find, but with a `+` instead of the `\;`.

```
find /tmp -name core -type f -exec /bin/rm -f {} +
```

This version doesn't call `/bin/rm` for every file, but bundles the arguments, just as `xargs` does.

Comment: If you use `time` before each of the above commands, you can notice that `xargs` still beats `exec` with the `+`.

Comment: It doesn't here and there is actually no technical reason for one to be significantly faster or slower than the other. The `+` solution is more elegant (IMHO) and works with all find implementations while the `-print0` one is GNU specific and unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 5):

The first version can be faster than the second: `xargs` will pass multiple files at a time to `rm`, but `find` will call `rm` once per file.

So there can be less fork/exec calls with the first version.

(If there is a single match or none at all, the second version is likely to be faster though: no need to exec `xargs` itself.)

But I don't think that's a good criteria for choosing one or the other. In this specific case, you don't have to worry about strange filenames, but in general you should. The second version is safer, so you should, generally, use that.

Comment: Another point is that in the pipe version, the rm and find are working in parallel (at least if there is enough files to remove). I'd not be surprised that some times it helps, sometimes it hinders the performance.

Comment: Interesting point, hadn't thought too much about that. For large number of files and dirs, total time is going to be dominated by directory read/update I/O in any case I believe, so most likely none of this actually matters :)